# How to enable Firefox notification that is blocked?

Tags: firefox

Sometimes when I open a new website in Firefox, this kind of dialog shows up.

[image]

I believe this is from Firefox native Notification feature.

Usually I just disable the notifications. But I just noticed recently that I really like this feature in some app that I accidentally enable.

How do I reenable this for some web that I already disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reenable this to the default on a per-site basis by right-clicking somewhere in a blank spot of the site (or pressing Ctrl-I on Windows or Cmd-I on Mac) and then selecting "View Page Info" from the opening menu. This opens a window with a "Permissions" tab. I that, scroll down to the very bottom until you see "Show Notifications" as the third-to-last entry. you can choose it to the option you wanted.